Where should a random generator be stored in C++?
Currently, I'm used to do this whenever I need to generate a random number in C++:
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned short int> distribution(0,UPPERBOUND);
distribution(gen);

But, I figured that in my last project, I found myself doing this in several methods of the same class. I was wondering whether it was good practice and efficient to store the random_device in the class as an attribute and initialize it in the constructor? My methods are called several times, sometimes in a row, and I'm affraid it could somewhat jeopardize the quality of the randomness.
class test{
      private: 
        std::mt19937  generator; 
      public:
        test() : generator(std::random_device{}()) { }
  };

Thank you for your answers!

std::random_device rd; std::mt19937 gen(rd()); is expensive do only once per-thread.

You are just providing a seed value to the mt19937 engine, it should be fine. random_device::operator() returns a value in range [min(), max()].

@kiner_shah have you considered where a non-deterministic seed comes from?

@RichardCritten, I meant to say, using it the way he is using is fine. The seed should be used to initialize the engine, and then the uniform distribution's operator() can reuse that engine again and again whenever needed.

If the instances of the class are meant to live for a long time then it's fine. Otherwise your program will construct an expensive RNG object per instance and then destruct it. It's better to have one per thread to avoid synchronization as well.

Each of these utilities have their own limitations.
For example:

std::random_device is not useful if your implementation has no non-deterministic source available.
std::uniform_int_distribution is UB if you use it with char (signed or unsigned).

For these reasons, I would not recommend to expose and use them directly but to wrap them into a function of yours instead so that you can ensure that things are always done right when generating a random number. By the way, that solves the "where to store them" issue.
The std::random_device and the std::mt19937 (or std::mt19937_64) generator do not need to be created more than once per thread since they are meant to be reused so making them thread_local (which implies static) would solve that issue and save the otherwise unnecessary repeated construction cost.
Such a function may look like:
template <std::integral Integral>
Integral randi(Integral min, Integral max)
{
    static_assert(!std::is_same<typename std::make_unsigned<Integral>::type, unsigned char>::value, "Error: The given \"Integral\" template type does not match the std::uniform_int_distribution type requirements.");

    if(min > max)
        std::swap(min, max);

    auto seed = []() -> unsigned int
    {
        std::random_device rd;
        if(static_cast<bool>(rd.entropy()))
            return rd();
        else
            return static_cast<unsigned int>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
    };
    thread_local std::mt19937_64 gen(seed());

    return std::uniform_int_distribution<Integral>(min, max)(gen);
}

And be used like:
randi(42, 3600);               // int
randi<unsigned short>(16, 24); // unsigned short
// ...


Why preserve std::random_device and the seed when you only need them once?

@HolyBlackCat Mostly for readability. rd is used twice (for entropy() and for operator()()) and I didn't want to construct it twice. For the seed, I found it clearer to not write the lambda directly into the std::mt19937_64 constructor's argument ^^ So if the little extra memory used is not an issue, I would always prefer the code readability but I agree it's completely opinion-based ^^

auto seed = []() -> unsigned int {std::random_device rd; ... would let you remove thread_local from both the random_device and the seed lambda.

@HolyBlackCat Oh right, I didn't think of that. But I think the thread_local would still be necessary for the lambda unless I overloked something ? (I don't want the seed to be reconstructed at each call if it's to be used only at the first one)

Constructing a captureless lambda is a no-op. Sure, you can make it static constexpr (calling from multiple threads is fine), but it probably won't change anything.

@HolyBlackCat I didn't know it was no-op :o I always saw lambdas like sort of hidden classes (because of the capture list) but indeed, here it's basically more like a normal function (lazyness to not write a proper separated function to generate a seed). I corrected it !
